# Leaflet: How to use CRS.Simple with TileLayer?

Tags: leaflet

I have a 2048x4096 tiled map with 256x256 tiles.

In Leaflet with a Tilelayer and CRS.Simple, it shows up as about 120x230 pixels instead of the 2048x4096 I expected.

What's going on and how do I control this?

Comment: Hard to help you with the little information provided. Please share some code, screenshots, sketches to explain your situation. If possible, provide a live example, e.g. using JSBin, Plunker, JSFiddle, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If I examine my map closely, it actually ends up as 128x256 pixels.

I think what's happening is that CRS.Simple, probably inadvertently, scales a tiled map down to fit within one tile.

As it happens, that works quite well for my purpose, so I don't need to pursue this any further.

Comment: I noticed the same behavior, but I can't manage to tweak the tileSize / bounds to have the map displayed once without copying/wrapping (with noWrap true) at the highest zooms. How did you achieve it?